# Can someone help me to provide space between the time stamps on x-axis

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

[image: Time series plot]

I am creating a Timeseries plot using angular highcharts as shown in the picture above. 
I used mintickinterval. The problem with this approach is when I zoom, only one time stamp is visible.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a navigator. It helps you when you have large data.

```
Check this example

    https://jsfiddle.net/dev_cho2/5L0keom8/
```

Comment: thank you, but is there no other way to provide space between the timestamps ?